# Can't send custom events to Google Analytics/Firebase from my Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics

I'm kind of new programming events for Google Analytics (nowadays Firebase?) under iOS.
Right now I'm coding some Objective C app and I need to track some custom events inside said app (The typical button press, etc...)

I've successfully installed all the needed pods, .plist files, etc, under my XCode 8.2.1, no problem.

My doubts come now:

I've added some random advice I found reading many pages, and applied them onto the desired places in my code, but apparently I can't create/send custom Events.

My current setup is this one:

-In my App Delegate I've added these lines of code:

```
// Google Analytics
// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
//
NSError *configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

// Optional: configure GAI options.
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions
gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;  // remove before app release


// THIS lines are just a test... They don't make a difference if I comment them.
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:@"TEST_DIMENSION_VALUE" ];
```

-In my ViewController I've added these other lines:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_status"
                                                      action:@"init_scan_process"
                                                       label:@"hello"
                                                       value:@1] build]];
```

Ok, what happens in runtime while I press the button firing that event? Apparently nothing.
If I'm inside Firebase/Analytics panel I don't get any custom event appearing. I get generic non explicitly sent ones ("entered into some screen", etc...).

I've added the debug verbose mode into XCode (for real time debugging inside Firebase/Analytics panel -> StreamView -> DebugView.
This way I get all kind of real time events (in 1 minute time slices)... But not my custom ones.

Apparently XCode sends and forwards my json data from my custom events to Google... But then I don't know where to find them onto the Firebase/Analytics panel.

I'm out of clues, any obvious hint I might have forgotten?
I'm open to questions from more advanced users having dealt with similar situations in the past.

Grettings and thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `[FIRApp configure]` in `appDidLaunch`?

Comment: Also looks like you're logging to Google Analytics and not FireBase analytics. Firebase analytics code looks different. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events

Comment: I've been following (and wanting to use) Google Analytics tutorials, not Firebase. I've used this one: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?hl=es-419

Every mention to "Firebase" in my original question was there because later on, when I enter into my Associated Google Analytics account panel, it just says "Firebase" onto the top left part of the screen.
In my tutorials, no [FIRApp configure] line appeared whatsoever, so I didn't use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As usual self-answered question.

I finally found out why my custom events were not appearing where I looked for them.
I was looking for them in some Firebase console/panel. Why? No idea, as following Google tutorials (can't remember which one), I ended in some fancy Firebase panel (correctly associated with my google account).

The misleading part was that in that Firebase panel, there is a section named "Analytics" which showed some data about your iOS app, but not really what Google Analytics would show...

Whatever, reading more *internets* I finally found I should have gone to analytics.google.com to begin with. 
Once I entered there, I finally found the Events section I was looking for, where I could see the custom hits I programmed inside my APP.
There is even a real time Events section, where I can see events grouped by the last 5 minutes of interaction.

Sucess!!

Thanks and greetings.